# how to get post response after/when 500 internal server error angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error when I call a post service. I do have an interceptor that will open a dialog, though the dialog comes empty.
It seems I can't get the answer of this call because of the error 500. But I can see the answer on chrome debugger. How can I get the response, despite the error?

My code:

```
 -interceptor:


  responseError: function (rejection) {
                var bcsAuth = $injector.get('bcsAuth');
                var MobileLoading = $injector.get('MobileLoading');
                var MobileDialog = $injector.get('MobileDialog');
 switch (rejection.status) {case 500:
                        if (rejection.statusText.toLowerCase().trim() == 'internal server error') {
                            MobileDialog.alert("error", rejection.data.message, "OK");

                        } else if (rejection.data.code && rejection.data.code == 'ETIMEDOUT') {

                            MobileDialog.alert("WARNING", "CONNECTION_TIMEOUT", "OK");
                        }
```

debug on google chrome:

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you are posting to a domain you have control over, why not fix the internal server error rather than ignoring it? I don't know much about angularjs, but I generally understand why internal server errors pop up. Are you trying to make a http request on a https connection? That should be the first question you ask yourself.

Comment: @Martin according to my co worker, responsible for the server, the error is 500 for security reasons and he doesn't want to change this from error 500 to any other type.  I know why the error 500 is happening as well, simply if password and code are wrong, it will give that error,, this is  not on login but on the change password feature

Comment: "*...according to my co worker, responsible for the server, the error is 500 for security reasons and he doesn't want to change this from error 500 to any other type*".  Sounds like a weird excuse. It does not effect "security" one bit ...

Comment: Since You are getting an empty dialog, any of one if else statement is getting executed. What I suspect is rejection.data.message might be empty. You need to verify the formant of json thrown by the server. The response you are showing is raw response or parsed. In either case it's not showing any nested json object. It's simple text to me.

Comment: 500 should NEVER be returned by a service endpoint for authentication/authorization issues.  500 should be reserved for errors being generated at the server level.

Comment: @user1011627 how can I say this to my senior though? Anyways, I am trying to find a way to work with this 500 error in a way I can still read the response

Comment: I don't know the person in question so I can't answer that part.  As for the 500, what do you mean "in a way I can still read the response".  If you are trying to get to that message, "New Password must be different...", where does that exist in the response that is being returned.  The fact that the server returns a status code of 500 should prevent you from traversing what is sent back by the server.  Is rejection.data.message what you are trying to pull from?   If so, have you validated that data is truly defined by the server's response.  Currently, the code assumes it is populated.

Comment: ty @MukeshVerma, the problem was I was trying to get the .message, but there is no .message since the answer is raw text and json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since You are getting an empty dialog, any of one if else statement is getting executed. What I suspect is rejection.data.message might be empty. You need to verify the formant of json thrown by the server. The response you are showing is raw response or parsed. In either case it's not showing any nested JSON object. It's simple text to me.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: the answer was to cut out the .message

and just stay with rejection.data , since it was a raw text message and not a json object

MobileDialog.alert("error", rejection.data, "OK");